# Add screen modes in settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created UI options menu for graphics and screen. The thing is that I was able to add obly a boolean value for fullScreen mode. I need to add a dropdown with 3 modes: fullscreen, windowed, and windowed with no frame (stretched to the entire screen size). How do I get the third mode?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this sample code](http://www.pixelstudio.nl/?p=204). It uses the `user32.dll` library, though, so you most likely need to reference it in your project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class WindowMod : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rect screenPosition;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong (IntPtr hwnd,int  _nIndex ,int  dwNewLong);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos (IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow ();

// not used rigth now
//const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
//const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
//const uint SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
//const uint SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080;

const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
const int WS_BORDER = 1;

void Start ()
{
    SetWindowLong(GetForegroundWindow (), GWL_STYLE, WS_BORDER);
    bool result = SetWindowPos (GetForegroundWindow (), 0,(int)screenPosition.x,(int)screenPosition.y, (int)screenPosition.width,(int) screenPosition.height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
}
```

With this method your best bet would be to:

1. Create an enum for all options, for example `public enum WindowMode { FullScreen, Borderless, Window }`
2. Create a manager class with a method that takes the enum as an argument: `public void SetWindowMode(WindowMode wm // or int) {...}`
3. Wire it up so that the method is called whenever an item is selected from the ComboBox on the Options menu with the UUI's `EventSystem` thingy
4. That's pretty much it.